# Scrapy dynamic feed export

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm trying to have Scrapy set the export file based on the input file. This is the code I'm trying:

```py
import scrapy


class VideosSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "videos"
    start_urls = []
    custom_settings = {
        "ITEM_PIPELINES": {
            "project.pipelines.VideosPipeline": 200,
            "project.pipelines.EpisodeImagesPipeline": 300,
        },
        "FILES_STORE": "episodes",
        "IMAGES_STORE": "episodes",
    }

    def __init__(self, urls_file=None, *args, **kwargs):
        # urls_file is a list of links (one per line)
        if urls_file:
            with open(urls_file, "r") as f:
                next(f)  # skip first line (header)
                self.start_urls = [url.strip() for url in f.readlines()]

            self.custom_settings["FEEDS"] = {
                Path(urls_file).with_suffix(".txt"): {
                    "format": "custom",
                },
            } # ideally would set the feeds with names corresponding to input file
```

The above however results an empty `FEEDS` setting in the pipeline:

```py
class VideosPipeline:
    def __init__(self, uri, files):
        self.uri = uri
        self.files = files

    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
        return cls(
            uri=crawler.settings.get("FEEDS"), # this is empty
            files=crawler.settings.get("FILES_STORE"),
        )

    def open_spider(self, spider):
        feeds = [k for k, v in self.uri.items() if k["format"] == "cistom"]

        self.exporter = CustomExporter(feeds[0])
```

And a small piece of code from the custom exporter:

```py
from scrapy.exporters import BaseItemExporter


class CustomExporter(BaseItemExporter):
    def __init__(self, file, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(dont_fail=True, **kwargs)
        self.file = file
```

Where am I going wrong?

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **URI parameters** in the `FEED` setting to dynamically set the expoted file path. It enables you to use any spider attribute to compose the `FEED` value.

---

**See this part from the docs**

Any other named parameter gets replaced by the spider attribute of the same name. For example, %(site_id)s would get replaced by the spider.site_id attribute the moment the feed is being created.
https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/feed-exports.html#storage-uri-parameters

---

So, on your example, it would be something like (note that I also changed the  file extension, since `txt` is not in the standard serialization formats:

```
class VideosSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "videos"
    start_urls = []
    custom_settings = {
        "ITEM_PIPELINES": {
            "project.pipelines.VideosPipeline": 200,
            "project.pipelines.EpisodeImagesPipeline": 300,
        },
        "FILES_STORE": "episodes",
        "IMAGES_STORE": "episodes",
        "FEED": {"file:///somepath/%(exported_file)s" : {"format": "csv"}}
    }

    def __init__(self, urls_file=None, *args, **kwargs):
        self.exported_file = str(Path(urls_file).with_suffix(".csv"))
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work, I'm using a function to set the variable but the pattern works.
Would it be possible to have the variable be dynamically set based on the current `start_url`?
For example if I wanted `somepath/{current_start_url}.txt` how would I set it?

Comment: I think you can just set the `exported_file` variable as `self.start_urls[0]`, like

`self.exported_file = self.start_urls[0]`

Comment: Actually I found there's an even better way: [FEED_URI_PARAMS](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/feed-exports.html#feed-uri-params) which I totally missed before